# Grouping records with with consecutive start and end dates -Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

We are migrating to a new record management system and I'm weeding through the issues with the data migration. Source data and destination data are all in Postgresql

In the source database we have multiple rows for the same vendor for each authorization code for that vendor and the start and end date of that authorization.

```
+----------+---------------+------------+-----------+
|  Vendor  | Authorization | Start Date | End Date  | 
+----------+---------------+------------+-----------+
| Vendor 1 | #####         | 1/1/2017   | 2/28/2017 | 
| Vendor 1 | #####         | 3/1/2017   | 4/15/2017 |
| Vendor 2 | #####         | 4/16/2017  | 5/31/2017 |
| Vendor 2 | #####         | 6/1/2017   | 7/12/2017 | 
| Vendor 1 | #####         | 7/13/2017  | 9/30/2017 |
+----------+---------------+------------+-----------+
```

In the destination database we have records for the active vendor relationship at a given time with a start date and an end date. (Auth # start and end dates are tracked separately) After migration the example listed previously should look like this.

```
+----------+------------+-----------+
|  Vendor  | Start Date | End Date  |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| Vendor 1 | 1/1/2017   | 4/15/2017 |
| Vendor 2 | 4/16/2017  | 7/12/2017 |
| Vendor 1 | 7/13/2017  | 9/30/2017 |
+----------+------------+-----------+
```

I think I should be able to accomplish this joining the table back on it self n-1 number of times where n is the largest number of consecutive authorization numbers for the same vendor which is probably around 10, which is doable but definitely not preferable.

Is there a more common method to group data by consecutive start and end dates?

Comment: It reads like you want to merge **overlapping** + consecutive ranges rather than just consecutive.  See [PostgreSQL query to detect overlapping time ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733385/) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a GROUPING AND WINDOW solution in this way:

> ```
> create table tbl (vendor text, auth text, StartDate Date, EndDate Date);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into tbl values
> ('Vendor 1', '#####', '20170101', '20170228'),
> ('Vendor 1', '#####', '20170301', '20170415'),
> ('Vendor 2', '#####', '20170416', '20170531'),
> ('Vendor 2', '#####', '20170601', '20170712'),
> ('Vendor 1', '#####', '20170703', '20170930');
> ```
>
> ```
> 5 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select vendor, min(startdate) as startdate, max(enddate) as enddate, grp
> from (
>       select vendor, auth, startdate, enddate, 
>              sum(rst) over (order by vendor, startdate) as grp
>       from (
>              select vendor, auth, startdate, enddate, 
>                     case when coalesce(lag(enddate) over (partition by vendor order by vendor, startdate), startdate) + 1 <> startdate then 1 end rst
>              from   tbl
>            ) t1
>      ) t2
> group by grp, vendor
> order by startdate
> ```
>
> ```
> vendor   | startdate  | enddate    | grp
> :------- | :--------- | :--------- | --:
> Vendor 1 | 2017-01-01 | 2017-04-15 |   1
> Vendor 2 | 2017-04-16 | 2017-07-12 |   3
> Vendor 1 | 2017-07-03 | 2017-09-30 |   2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e736a46f95208f6863675aa1d338b4d0)*

Comment: I think you want to `ORDER BY startdate, enddate vendor` or similar?

Comment: Whatever about the inner subqueries, I don't think the `ORDER BY` for the outer one is definitively determined by anything but the last `ORDER BY`. The OP wanted an answer in `startdate` order AFAICS!

Comment: I read through it but have yet to try the solution. Thank you so much for posting it though. I've never used a window function and it's always exciting to learn something new.

Comment: This works awesome. Two notes for anyone else that may look to use this. It doesn't account for gaps between "auths" if the vendor before and after the gap match. (This is preferable for my purposes) And it does not account for nulls in the end date which to us indicate an open ended, current authorization. To account for the null I refereed to this question and replaced the Max(EendDate) witht he case statement. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286215/how-can-i-include-null-values-in-a-min-or-max

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.